# Using Scrapy to scrape data after form submit

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrape content from listing detail page that can only be viewed by clicking the 'view' button which triggers a form submit . I am new to both Python and Scrapy

Example markup

```
<li><h3>Abc Widgets</h3>
     <form action="/viewlisting?id=123" method="post">
        <input type="image" src="/images/view.png" value="submit" >
     </form>
</li>
```

My solution in Scrapy is to extract form actions then use Request to return the page with a callback to parse it for for the desired content. However I have hit a few issues

1. I'm getting the following error  "request url must be str or unicode"
2. secondly when I hardcode a URL to overcome the above issue it seems my parsing function is returning what looks like a list

Here is my code  - with reactions of the real URLs

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from wfi2.items import Wfi2Item

class ProfileSpider(Spider):
    name = "profiles"

    allowed_domains = ["wfi.com.au"]
    start_urls = ["http://example.com/wps/wcm/connect/internet/wfi/Contact+Us/Find+Your+Local+Office/findYourLocalOffice.jsp?state=WA",
    "http://example.com/wps/wcm/connect/internet/wfi/Contact+Us/Find+Your+Local+Office/findYourLocalOffice.jsp?state=VIC",
    "http://example.com/wps/wcm/connect/internet/wfi/Contact+Us/Find+Your+Local+Office/findYourLocalOffice.jsp?state=QLD",
    "http://example.com/wps/wcm/connect/internet/wfi/Contact+Us/Find+Your+Local+Office/findYourLocalOffice.jsp?state=NSW",
    "http://example.com/wps/wcm/connect/internet/wfi/Contact+Us/Find+Your+Local+Office/findYourLocalOffice.jsp?state=TAS"
    "http://example.com/wps/wcm/connect/internet/wfi/Contact+Us/Find+Your+Local+Office/findYourLocalOffice.jsp?state=NT"
    ]



    def parse(self, response):

        hxs =  Selector(response)
        forms = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="area-managers"]//*/form')

        for form in forms:

            action = form.xpath('@action').extract()
            print "ACTION: ", action
            #request = Request(url=action,callback=self.parse_profile)
            request = Request(url=action,callback=self.parse_profile)
            yield request

    def parse_profile(self, response):
        hxs =  Selector(response)
        profile = hxs.xpath('//*[@class="contentContainer"]/*/text()')

        print "PROFILE", profile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I'm getting the following error "request url must be str or unicode"

Please have a look at the scrapy documentation for `extract()`. [It says](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/selectors.html?highlight=extract#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract) : "Serialize and return the matched nodes **as a list** of unicode strings" (bold added by me).

The first element of the list is probably what you want. So you could do something like:

```
    request = Request(url=response.urljoin(action[0]), callback=self.parse_profile)
```

> 2. secondly when I hardcode a URL to overcome the above issue it seems my
>      parsing function is returning what looks like a list

According to the documentation of [xpath](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/selectors.html?highlight=extract#scrapy.selector.Selector.xpath) it's a `SelectorList`. Add `extract()` to the `xpath` and you'll get a list with the text tokens. Eventually you want to clean up and join the elements that list before further processing.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and calling out the relevant sections of the docs